# HTTP Post in the WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am using the webview and which open the url and accept the login credential through post approach. I did that using the code so that user don't need to enter those after first login.

But I am unable to do so, I am sending the data using the POST approach but its not working not opening home page and How to check whether it UTF-8 or something else..

```
String data = "loginemailaddress=" + "username" + "&loginpassword=" + "password";
if(data != null) {
         myWebView.postUrl("https://www.pmtestonline.com/study.jsp", EncodingUtils.getBytes(data,"UTF-8"));
}
```

Comment: pass data direct to url as QueryString myWebView.postUrl("https://www.pmtestonline.com/study.jsp?loginemailaddress="+username + "&loginpassword=" + password);

Comment: postUrl accept two argument url and byte data...what i pass in your case in the second parameter

Comment: I used like this myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.pmtestonline.com/study.jsp?" + "loginemailaddress=" + "userid" + "&loginpassword=" + "password"); still not working..the url accept only post approach but you suggested here get approach..